# Use AJAX Response in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Essentially, I have a list of clients and a calendar beside this. The idea is that when a client is clicked then it find the availability and then return this information through a calendar plugin to show which days are available. Below is my code inside the 'click' function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "inc/available_dates_search.php",
    data: string,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){

        var result = eval(response);

        $('#date_calendar').glDatePicker({
            selectableDates: result
        });
    }
});
```

The property 'selectableDates' needs to be in the format `[{ date: new Date(2013, 8, 15) }]` when I perform `alert(result)` **it gives me the correct output**. This leads me to believe that the problem is with passing the value to the datepicker. Is it not possible to pass this response to the datepicker and if it is how can it be achieved?

I am using the glDatePicker, which can be found here: http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a problem with Ajax not getting the correct result or with the calendar plugin not accepting your invocation? Please be specific about what does not work, and link/tag the plugin you're using.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, the Ajax appears to be giving the correct result as, like mentioned, when I perform an alert of the result it shows the correct information. So it is just when trying to pass this value through to the calendar plugin that it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Then please tell use what plugin you are using. [edit] your question.

Comment: I'm using the glDatePicker plugin (http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/). Edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: If you can't get `glDatePicker` to work for you, the jQuery UI datepicker may help - possibly in conjunction with multiDatesPicker (http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: could you please post the response variable contents so that we know what needs to be converted?

Comment: The response I'm getting is: `[{ date: new Date(2013, 8, 15) }]`

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark since I never used glDatePicker

The problem is probably the fact the calendar already exists and it will not update. You will need to destroy it and re-initialize it. Or if the API has a way to update the dates, call that method.

If it is written correctly and has a destroy method, something like this should work.

```
$('#date_calendar').glDatePicker("destroy").glDatePicker({
     selectableDates: result
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! :) Unfortunately, my code already does this as I thought I had had the same brain-wave before posting on here.

Comment: GLDatepicker does not have a destroy method. https://github.com/glad/glDatePicker/blob/master/glDatePicker.js (for any fellow Googlers coming across this post this late in the game).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use callback, response evaluation might take too long.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "inc/available_dates_search.php",
 data: string,
 cache: false,
 success: function(response){
   (function(res, callback){
       // ... your code to process "res"
       result = xyz;
       callback(result);
   })(response, function(data){
       $('#date_calendar').glDatePicker({
          selectableDates: data
       });
   });

 }
```